# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT with let realm = try! Realm() after Xcode 11 Upgrade

Tags: swift, realm

For years I have been using a global variable for my Realm declaration in the AppDelegate as follow.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   ...
}
```

I just upgraded from Xcode 10.2 to Xcode 11 and now I'm getting a **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** error in line `let realm = try! Realm()`

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> (lldb)
>
> Realm.unsafeMutableAdressor

I'm using the same Swift version (4.2).

Why would it work on Xcode 10.2 but not in Xcode 11?

Comment: Just tried that exact code and it's working here. XCode 11, Swift 5. Try updating your project to Realm 3.18.0

Comment: Hmm, interesting thank you for trying and verifying. I'm using `cocoapods`, do you know how do I specify a specific version of Realm in my Pod file? I currently have it as `pod 'RealmSwift'`in my Pod file.

Comment: FYI - Running `pod install` shows `Using Realm (3.14.2)`, `Using RealmSwift (3.14.2)`

Comment: Updated my `podfile` to 3.18 (`pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.18'`), cleaned build folder and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.